# Handling missing data in API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, mongoose

I have a route handler that requires some data (`car.name`) be passed to it in order to serve its function.

```
carRouter.route('/create')
  .post(carController.create)

function create(req, res, next) {
  const carInstance = new carModel({
    activated: false,
    name: body.car.name,
```

If there is no `body.car.name`, express crashes.

I could handle this by adding the following check :

```
if (body.car.name) {
  function create(req, res, next) {
```

But that quickly becomes cumbersome with a large number of model properties.

I already have validation setup in my `CarSchema` itself, so I would like to delegate validation to mongoose, and avoid the application crashing if there's missing data in the request.

I have looked at quite a few real world examples on github to try and find how this is handled, with mixed results.

What is a proper approach to handling this basic situation?

Comment: If the data is missing, what do you want the result of the API call to be?

Comment: @jfriend00 I would like to return 40*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TypeError` being thrown for attempt of reading propery of non-object? Maybe this helps:

```
name: body.car ? body.car.name : null
```

Or, if you don't care about `name` being `undefined`:

```
name: body.car && body.car.name
```

Comment: What if `body.car` exists but `body.car.name` doesn't?

Comment: Quering non-existent properties is okay is JS, but not querying properties of non-existent objects. `body.car.name` simply evaluates to `undefined`.

Comment: Ok. `body` will always exist?

Comment: It is related to other parts of your code. In Node, and particulary Express, there is `req` object passed to handler function. It is `http` module's wrapper around HTTP request, and it has `req.body` field as long as HTTP request has. You're handling POST request, so in your handler function `req.body` should definitely contain all the data (you must be using `body-parser` for it).

Comment: :p reposted:  
Ok. So I could just place the body.car existence check before the creation of the Model like such `if (body.car) { const carInstance = new carModel({ activated: false, name: body.car.name`?

Comment: That's right! That could be the most obvious way. But what if you'll need to check for `body.car`, `body.owner`, `body.driver` and all other complex entries in `body`, the code will become pretty huge so some optimization may needed.